# svelte - run code with side effects inside of for loop

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have the following Svelte component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    const tests = [ {txt: "aasdasdadss", foo: () => console.log("side ffect") }]
</script>
<div>
    {#each tests as test}
        <script>
            test.foo()
        </script>
        <div>{test.txt}</div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Is there way to make `test` defined so, I can call `foo`?

This is closer, but it renders the `null`:

```
<script lang="ts">
    const tests = [ {txt: "aasdaasdasdsdadss", foo: null }]
    tests[0].foo = () => {
    }
</script>
<div>
    {#each tests as test}
        {
            test.foo() || null
        }
        <div>{test.txt}</div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: what are you expecting it to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`use:action`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) might be what you are looking for [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4fcdccc63154a5ea3bc412e1f4e94ee?version=3.46.4)

```
<script>
    const tests = [ {txt: "aasdaasdasdsdadss", foo: () => console.log("side ffect") }]
</script>

<div>
    {#each tests as test}        
        <div use:test.foo>{test.txt}</div>
    {/each}
</div>
```